# Can't fetch json object from server?

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask, server

> When i try to fetch object from server but it not fetching anything..when i try to fetch from browser url way  its working fine it fetching all the data from database but in app it not displaying listview in xampp also it was working fine when i was using this url `url = new URL("http://192.168.1.110/food_nearby/");` then i change it into my domain name then now it showing nothing

```
 @Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(final Pair<String, String>... params) {

    int count = params.length;
    URL url = null;
    int responseCode = 0;
    jsonObject = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.gampzz.com/food_nearby/");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Probably problem with access to your domain. What is the error you got?

Comment: Check your domain dns status: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dns%3agampzz.com&run=toolpage#

Comment: i dont think there is problem in my domain or anything .. error i am gettnig is no internet connection

Comment: http://gampzz.com/food_nearby/index.php?action=searchFood&money=50 here is my url u can check its fetching all the result from database